# How to initialize a constant to an already existing object_id in postgresql table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way assign a constant to existing sql entries?

For example, Sarah's House is in houses.id = 2. Sarah exists in people.id = 1.

Exploring in Rails for the first time, I followed an assignment that had asked me to setup a simple project to model the relationships between people and houses. Each house would have an address and a person would belong to a house. You could check the residents of a house and see who lived there.

I added pry-rails to my gemfile in order to boot the rails console into pry, and from there initialized my people and house.

Unfortunately, I made a gaff and closed pry after I .save!'d. I queried the tables in a second terminal and did see that my people/house were stored in their respective tables.

When I do House.all I get something that looks like this:

```
  House Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "houses".* FROM "houses"
=> [#<House:0x00007fbe916496d0
  id: 2,
  address: "123 Main st.",
  created_at: Fri, 03 May 2019 21:39:14 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 03 May 2019 21:39:14 UTC +00:00>]
```

I originally did the following in Pry:

```
SarahsHouse = House.new(address: '123 Main St.')
Sarah = Person.new(name: 'Sarah', house_id: 'SarahsHouse.id')
SarahsHouse.save!
Sarah.save!
```

I'd hope to be able to tie Sarah and whomever else has an entry in the people table to a specific entry so I continue to test my models.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple.

Class.find(primary_id)

Using this you can initialize a variable to a specific table class obj.